# Elasticsearch mapping for object with dynamic keys

Tags: elasticsearch

I have simple document with this mapping:

```js
'product': {
  'properties': {
    'name': { 'type': 'string' },
    'shops': { 
      'type': 'object', 
      'index_name': 'shop', 
      'properties': {
        'name': { 'type': 'string' },
        'url': { 'type': 'string' },
        'price': { 'type': 'integer' },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document look like this:

```js
{ 
  'name': 'Kindle', 
  'shops': [ 
    { 'name': 'amazon', 'url': 'http://...', 'price': 79 },
    { 'name': 'ebay', 'url': 'http://...', 'price': 99 }
}
```

But I want store documents in this format:

```js
{
  'name': 'Kindle',
  'shops': {
    'amazon': { 'url': 'http://...', 'price': 79 },
    'ebay': { 'url': 'http://...', 'price': 99 }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do mapping for this? Or I should create only object 'shops' and keep it schema-less.

Comment: What kind of queries are you planning to do?

Comment: Queries will be simple, in most cases string queries for select products for specific shop. For example:
   
   {
     "query_string" : {
       "query" : "_exists_:shops.amazon.url"
     }
   }

I prefer to store shops as object rather than array, because of easier manipulation in ruby.

Comment: @mrazicz did you mange to overcome this?

Comment: Hi, yeah, I use solution from answer below. But after all, I ended up with my original solution. Turns out, that array of objects is better for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use a dynamic_template with a path_match ("shops.*") [1].

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-root-object-type.html

Comment: This could be works. But now, how can I check if templates work? any suggestions?

Comment: Just add the documents, then retrieve the mapping.

Comment: link is broken. New link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-root-object-type.html

Comment: @ejain - can you share your es mapping for this example?